# How can I make the match fail if the first occurence of a pattern doesn't match a condition?

Tags: regex

I have a comma-separated string of `key=value` pairs like this:

```
foo=1,foo=1,bar=2
```

In this string I want to capture the value of the *first* `foo`, but only if it's immediately followed by `bar=2`.

#### Examples:

- In this string, the value `1` should be captured:

  ```
   baz=0,foo=1,bar=2,foo=3,bar=4
  ```
- In this string, nothing should be captured:

  ```
   baz=0,foo=1,foo=1,bar=2
  ```

My current solution uses a tempered greedy token, but that forces me to duplicate the `foo=[^,]*,` part of the regex:

```
^(?:(?!foo=[^,]*,).)*foo=([^,]*),bar=2(?:,|$)
```

Is there any way to do this without having to duplicate such a big part of the regex?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do everything in one regex?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, I'm curious if it's doable :)

Comment: I tried capturing the `foo..` part in a group and recursing that capture group again, but it seems that it's unable to capture *inside* of that capture group while recursing. https://regex101.com/r/CbGXKi/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy with [backtracking control verbs](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs):

```
(?<![^,])foo=([^,]*)(*COMMIT),bar=2(?![^,])
```

We match a position not preceded by a non-comma character (i.e. the start of the string or immediately after `,`), followed by `foo=`, followed by 0 or more non-comma characters (which we capture). This is the `foo=...` part.

We then commit to the first match found and require a `,bar=2` match, not followed by a non-comma character (i.e. a `,` or the end of the string).

Comment: Can you use these keywords in the PHP `preg` suite too?

Comment: @Mav I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: This only works in select regex engines.**

Some regex engines have a "feature" that we can abuse: Capture groups in lookaheads are possessive; once they have matched they can never change their value again.

Making use of this "feature", the regex can be written like this:

```
.*?(?!\1)thing_you_want_the_first_occurrence_of(?=())rest_of_the_regex
```

In this specific case, that looks like this (the indices of the capture groups are shifted by 1 since `foo=([^,]*)` contains a capture group):

```
.*?(?!\2)(?<![^,])foo=([^,]*),(?=())bar=2(?![^,])
```

So, how does it work?

After the first occurrence of `foo=` is found, the group `(?=())` matches. Because it's inside a lookahead, it can never change its value anymore - not even backtracking can affect it. So from this point onwards, `(?!\2)` will never match again. The fact that the first occurrence of `foo=` has been found is now "locked in" and cannot be undone. If the regex backtracks and tries to make the `.*?` match more text, the `(?!\2)` prevents this.

Demo using python's [PyPI `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```py
>>> pattern = r'.*?(?!\2)(?<![^,])foo=([^,]*),(?=())bar=2(?![^,])'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,bar=2,foo=3,bar=4').group(1)
'1'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,foo=1,bar=2')
>>>
```