# How does adding some text make this regex match the input even though there's no lookahead?

Tags: python, regex, pypi-regex

While working on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53035860/1222951), I came up with this regex:

```
(?:(?!\2)(?:,foo=([^,]*),(?=())|.))*\2bar=2
```

<sup>(Note: this regex requires the [PyPI `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/))</sup>

(Short explanation: The regex relies on the fact that capture groups in lookaheads can't change their value after they've matched once, so after the first `foo=` is found, the `(?=())` matches and from that point onwards `(?!\2)` will always fail.)

This regex works correctly with the 2 examples given in the question:

```
>>> pattern = r'(?:(?!\2)(?:,foo=([^,]*),(?=())|.))*\2bar=2'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,bar=2,foo=3,bar=4').group(1)
'1'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,foo=1,bar=2')
>>>
```

But something strange happens if there's an occurrence of `foo=` *after* a `bar=2`:

```
>>> # this doesn't match, as expected:
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'notfoo=1,bar=2')
>>> # but how the heck does it match this ?!
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'notfoo=1,bar=2,foo=3,')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='notfoo=1,bar=2'>
```

As you can see, the string `'notfoo=1,bar=2,foo=3,'` produced a match of `notfoo=1,bar=2`. The `foo=3,` isn't even included in the match, but if it's removed, the regex no longer matches! How is this possible? Is this a bug in the `regex` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually makes perfect sense. The reason for this behavior is simple: backtracking.

The sequence of events is as follows:

1. The greedy group `(?:...)*` advances one character at a time until it finally finds an occurrence of `foo=` at `,foo=3,`
2. The regex attempts to match `bar=2`, but this fails
3. The regex backtracks 1 character at a time until `bar=2` matches, giving us a result of `notfoo=1,bar=2`.

So, what can we do about this? We can move the `bar=2` *into* the greedy group and use another capture group to assert that the regex matched successfully:

```
(?:(?!\2)(?:,foo=([^,]*),(?=())bar=2()|.))*\3
```

```
>>> pattern = r'(?:(?!\2)(?:,foo=([^,]*),(?=())bar=2()|.))*\3'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,bar=2,foo=3,bar=4').group(1)
'1'
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'baz=0,foo=1,foo=1,bar=2')
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'notfoo=1,bar=2')
>>> regex.match(pattern, 'notfoo=1,bar=2,foo=3,')
>>>
```